# How to expose minikube in GCP VM

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I created a debian VM in GCP and installed kubectl and minikube. I deployed one image in the kubectl. I exposed the service using the command `kubectl expose deployment hw --type=NodePort --port=80`. It exposed in port 31343. But it is not accessible using the external ip of the VM. I added firewall rule to traffic to the port. But still it is not working. How can I access the site using the external ip of the VM.

*I know, I can use the GKE. But I need to try the kubernetes installation and configuration. That's why I following these steps.*

Comment: Could you please share the command you've used to start minikube custer with all arguments?

Comment: minikube start --driver=virtualbox

Comment: @NOBLEM.O. how did you enabled `VT-X/AMD-v` for minikube with virtualbox on a VM?

Comment: @Spook, I followed https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#enablenestedvirt to create a linux vm supporting virtualisation.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by using nginx proxy. May be using kubeadm as mentioned in the previous answer was the standard method. But I didn't get enough reference in the web.
We can use the GCP vm external ip to connect to the nginx server and it will redirect the request to the minikube. Also return the response back.

1. Install nginx in the linux vm using `sudo apt install nginx`
2. Create a nginx config file `sudo vim /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf`
3. Add following lines to the file. Replace  and .

   ```
   upstream app_server_32108 {
       server <minikube ip>:<port>;
   }    
   server {
       listen 80;
       location /proxy {
          proxy_pass http://app_server_32108/;
       }
   }
   ```
4. `sudo nginx -t`
5. Restart nginx server using `sudo systemctl reload nginx`
6. Now the content hosted in minikube can access using `http://<vm ip>/proxy`

If it is not accessible edit nginx config file `sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add comment to the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` by adding # as prefix.

> `#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

Restart nginx and try again. (Follow steps 4, 5 and 6).

Comment: if you face the issue of being unable to restart the Nginx service, here's a solution for that. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379425/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

Answer (score 0):

[Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) is basically a VM, so you are running a VM inside a VM.

You have exposed `deployment` from your Minikube to the VM, you can check what is the address of your Minikube using `$ minikube ip` or `$ minikube status`.

In order for this to work now you would need to setup a `proxy` on your GCP VM that would send traffic to `minikube`.

I would recommend using [`kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) and setting up [single control-plane cluster with kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

Comment: I have the same issue, do you have an example of how I can do this outside the cluster on a GCE? my minikube server is working fine and can access the svc from the ip from external i but that's only with in the GCE. How do I map to the GCE External IP so it's available externally outside the GCE?

Comment: The link you provided seems to be specific to creating a cluster, I guess in this case, it's about using an existing minikube cluster upon further reading.

Answer (score 0):

So the few answers above are probably things you should do, what you also should do is allow the port in the VPC firewall

Consider the firewall rule you need either through the web interface or from the console you can apply it like the comment below

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create "allow-internal-memcache" --allow=tcp:31343 --source-ranges="10.0.0.0/22,10.0.0.0/14" --description="Allow internal traffic and drop outside"
```

this comment is meant for something else.